# Java: Retain leading zero in output

Tags: java, rsa, padding

I have a Java program which creates a byte array `0x00 0x02 0x03 0x00`. I convert it into `BigInteger` type. But when I reconvert it into a byte array, I get the output without a leading zero `2 3 0`. The following is the code:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] {0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00};
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(b);
byte[] b2 = b1.toByteArray();

for (byte aB2 : b2) 
    System.out.print(aB2 + " ");
```

How can I retain the leading zero?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a leading 0 if you print the b array??

Comment: Yes: Output: `0 2 3 0`

Comment: So that's by design. 0100 as int is 100 and making this to a String will be 100 without leading 0.

Comment: Why is this down voted??

Comment: What is the point of sending a `byte[]` through a `BigInteger` like that? You do know that `b1` is not the number `230`, right? It's `131840`. So why would you expect the number `131840` to be the two's-complement bytes `0x00 0x02 0x03 0x00`? Why not expect `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x03 0x00`? Since `BigInteger` stored the number `131840`, it will just return that value in whatever representation you ask for, without *any* leading zeroes. Why would you expect it to add leading zeroes? How many should it output?

Comment: @Andreas, according to PKCS#1, I need an encoded message as `0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00 || M`. When decoding, I need to check whether the first octet is `0x00` and accordingly process.

Comment: What does any of that have to do with the question? If you need by build a particular 5-byte sequence, why are you using `BigInteger` and conversion to/from [two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)? Do you even know what that is?

Comment: The leading zero in PKCS#1 padding is just a fiction, emphasizing that the integer being exponentiated is strictly less than the modulus.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. [BigInteger](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.%3Cinit%3E%28byte%5B%5D%29) does not store that information.

```
public BigInteger(byte[] val) {
    if (val.length == 0)
        throw new NumberFormatException("Zero length BigInteger");

    if (val[0] < 0) {
        mag = makePositive(val);
        signum = -1;
    } else {
        mag = stripLeadingZeroBytes(val);     // (!) <-- watch this
        signum = (mag.length == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    }
    if (mag.length >= MAX_MAG_LENGTH) {
        checkRange();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to check if there is a leading zero. How do I do that then?

Comment: Then you should store the data in a structure which retains that. E.g. you can retain the original byte array or invent a boolean flag telling if you had a leading zero and reuse that later.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this quite simply if you know how many bytes to expect, simply add them back to the output `byte[]`.

In Kotlin this would look something like:

```kotlin
fun BigInteger.byteArrayPaddedToSize(size: Int): ByteArray {
    val byteArrayRepresentation = toByteArray().takeLast(size).toByteArray()
    return if (byteArrayRepresentation.size == size) {
        byteArrayRepresentation
    } else {
        val difference = size - byteArrayRepresentation.size
        ByteArray(difference) { 0x00 } + byteArrayRepresentation
    }
}
```